# Dynamically load/import split vendor chunks/bundles via Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a simple sample application that is structured thusly:

```
/dist
    index.html
    app.bundle.js
    moduleA.bundle.js
    moduleB.bundle.js
    vendors~app~moduleA~moduleB.bundle.js
    [...sourcemaps]
/node_modules
    [...]
/src
    index.js
    moduleA.js
    moduleB.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Dependency Pulls</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

src/index.js

```
import _ from 'Lodash';
import printA from './moduleA.js';
import printB from './moduleB.js';

function component() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');

  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack', '4'], ' ');

  btn.innerHTML = 'printA. Click me and check the console.';
  btn.onclick = printA;
  element.appendChild(btn); 

  btn = document.createelement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'printB. Click me and check the console.';
  btn.onclick = printB;
  element.appendChild(btn); 

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

src/moduleA.js

```
import printB from './moduleB.js';

export default function printA() {
  console.log('AAA I get called from moduleA.js!');
}
```

src/moduleB.js

```
import _ from 'Lodash';

export default function printB() {
  console.log('BBB I get called from moduleB.js!');
}
```

/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    moduleA: './src/moduleA.js',
    moduleB: './src/moduleB.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
}
```

When I pull in app.bundle.js, I expect the vendor bundle to be auto-pulled as well, since it is a dependency for app.js. Currently, this is not happening - the vendor bundle is not loaded.  I'm not even seeing an attempt in the network tab.

How do I tell webpack to automatically load dependencies of a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack bundling/dependency management does not work exactly in that way. You need to manually add a `<script>` tag to the html for each bundle (entry).

However, you may want to look into using:

**html-webpack-plugin**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin

which will automatically inject the bundle references to your html.

**html-webpack-template**:

https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template

may also help with additional customization/features.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I'm pulling in an entry bundle by any GET request, shouldn't that entry bundle automatically pull it's non-entry chunks?

Comment: @HowDoIDoComputer when you  reference a bundle, it only includes dependencies that are already part of that bundle - there is no dynamic 'pull' of other dependencies (this all happens during build). You can verify what's in the bundle(s) by using `webpack-bundle-analyzer`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: Anyone know if there's still no way to do this? I'm basically trying to achieve the same as @HowDoIDoComputer, using webpack to create module bundles that are only consumed in JS. Adding script tags to a page is not an option for me, and I have no use for generated HTML either. I struggle to understand how the requirement that chunks need to be manually included doesn't render the `splitChunks` optimization useless in most cases. Optimizations like this should be largely orthongonal to the way the code is consumed, IMO :(